# Invoke resolvers of fields on nested execution levels in NestJS GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs

I'm building a GraphQL API in NestJS supporting queries for nested objects, but I don't know how to invoke existing resolvers on an object-type from a parent resolver's `@ResolveField()` instead of having to resolve every nested field and object-type from `@ResolveField`.

I want to do a query on a person with a pet with a toy to get the color of the toy.

I.e. I want to be able to resolve the following query in the best way possible:

```
{
  person(id: "id123") {
    name
    petId
    pet: {
      toy: {
        color
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following object types defined as entities:

**Person entity:**

```js
import { ObjectType, Field } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Pet } from 'src/pet/entities/pet.entity';
 

@ObjectType()
export class Person {
  @Field(() => String)
  id: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  name: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  petId: string;

  @Field(() => Pet)
  pet: Pet;
}
```

**Pet entity:**

```js
import { ObjectType, Field } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Toy } from 'src/toy/entities/toy.entity';
 

@ObjectType()
export class Pet {
  @Field(() => String)
  id: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  species: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  toyId: string;

  @Field(() => Toy)
  toy: Toy;
}
```

**Toy entity:**

```js
import { ObjectType, Field } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@ObjectType()
export class Toy {
  @Field(() => String)
  id: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  color: string;
}
```

Currently I resolve a person's `name` and `petId` using the decorator `@Query(() => Person, { name: "person" })` from my person `@Resolver`, and I resolve `pet` with `@ResolveField("pet", () => Pet)`. My problem is, that I don't know how to invoke the resolver of a Pet from within the `@ResolveField("pet", () => Pet)`. It seems natural, that I should be able to invoke a pet resolver to move on in the resolver tree instead of having to resolve pet as well as toy and every other sub-field from `@ResolveField("pet", () => Pet)` in the person resolver.

Shouldn't GraphQL be smart enough to invoke resolvers of nested objecttypes on nested execution levels?
Or should I really manually resolve the rest of the resolver tree from a `@ResolveField` decorated method?

Every example I've found directly makes a call to the child object-type's service method instead of its resolver.
Like [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#code-first-resolver) where an Author's posts are resolved from `@ResolveField()` by calling `postsService.findAll()`.

What can I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was there a solution ever found for this?  I'm chasing a similar, if not exactly the same, issue.